# Split a row into two halves?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I expect the following to layout the two headers near each others, but the result is that they are layed out under each other ..

Here is the tags:

```
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div class=".col-md-6">
        <h1>Drivers List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class=".col-md-6">
        <h1>Dispatches</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, what could be wrong?

Comment: As Jake745 noted, don't put a `.` in your class, and also generally speaking it's best to have one `<h1>` tag per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

AVOID DOT(.) IN CLASS

```
<div class="row show-grid">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1 class="pull-right">Drivers List</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h1>Dispatches</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```